# TableView loop through all cell for deleting them, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I was trying iterating through all cell in TableView and delete them. I call function DeleteAll:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
    @IBAction func DeleteAll(sender: UIButton) {
        //myTableView.reloadData()
        for j in 0..<myTableView.numberOfSections {
            for i in (myTableView.numberOfRowsInSection(j) - 1).stride(through: 0, by: -1) {
                let myIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: j)


                    print("I=" + String(i) + "section " + String(j))
                    self.tableView( myTableView, commitEditingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete, forRowAtIndexPath: myIndexPath)

            }
        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    var indexPathForSelectedRows = [NSIndexPath]()

    lazy var productLines: [ProductLine] = {
        return ProductLine.productLines()
    }()



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let selctedRow = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
            productLines[indexPath.section].products.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
            selctedRow.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
            self.tableView( tableView, commitEditingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete, forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        }

        let share = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Disable") { (action, indexPath) in

        }
        delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        share.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        return [delete, share]
    }



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        //self.tableView( tableView, commitEditingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete, forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)

        let row = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
        if row.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None {
            row.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
        }
        else {
            row.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
        }
    }
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let productLine = productLines[section]
        return productLine.name
    }

    //override func tableV

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return productLines.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        let productLine = productLines[section]
        return productLine.products.count
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("uppercaseString", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let productLine = productLines[indexPath.section]
        let product = productLine.products[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = product.title
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = product.description
        cell.imageView?.image = product.image
        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }
}
```

But I have had this error, and I don't find out what wrong. This is console log:

- I=3section 0
- I=2section 0
- I=1section 0
- I=0section 0
- I=8section 1
- fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
  value (lldb)

Comment: Seems pretty inefficient, why not just delete all of the items in your data source, and then do `tableView.reloadData`?

Comment: Thank, it's works, but main goal it's iterate over all cells and get them using method cellForRowAtIndexPath, not just remove all.

Comment: Which line had the nil access? Force unwrapping `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is a bad idea; this function will return nil if the cell isn't currently onscreen

Comment: let selctedRow = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

Comment: Thanks, but what function should I use for retrieve all cells?

Comment: Yes, that will return nil if the row isn't on screen, so force unwrapping is a bad idea. In fact calling the delegate methods yourself is a bad idea. If you want to reuse code then you should have your delegate method calla delete method. You can't retrieve all cells; you can only retrieve cells that are onscreen. You shouldn't need to retrieve all cells; you simply update your data model and have the table reflect those changes by reloading the table, reloading specific rows or inserting/deleting specific rows

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. And one more question, how can I delete last cell in my table without using cellForRowAtIndexPath? Just delete it from data source and reload data?

Comment: Yes, or if you only delete a single element, delete it from the data source and then call `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`

Comment: Thanks, Paulw=) You cool man)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes, that will return nil if the row isn't on screen, so force
>   unwrapping is a bad idea. In fact calling the delegate methods
>   yourself is a bad idea. If you want to reuse code then you should have
>   your delegate method calla delete method. You can't retrieve all
>   cells; you can only retrieve cells that are onscreen. You shouldn't
>   need to retrieve all cells; you simply update your data model and have
>   the table reflect those changes by reloading the table, reloading
>   specific rows or inserting/deleting specific rows

– Paulw11